# Split pandas df based on column name endings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

```
data = {"name": [], "value": [], "x1xyz": [], "x2xyz": [], "x3xyz":[], "x1abc": [], "x2abc": [], "x3abc": []}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['name', 'value', 'x1xyz', "x2xyz", "x3xyz", 'x1abc', "x2abc", "x3abc"])
```

And I wish to split into two separate dataframes based on how the colum names end i.e. into:

```
xyz = {"name": [], "value": [], "xyz": [], "xyz": [], "xyz": []}

xyz = pd.DataFrame (keep, columns = ['name', 'value', 'x1xyz', 'x2xyz', 'x3xyz'])

abc = {"name": [], "value": [], "x1abc": [], "x2abc": [], "x3abc": []}

abc = pd.DataFrame (keep, columns = ['name', 'value', 'x1abc', 'x2abc', 'x3abc'])
```

I am not really sure how to approach this?

In the real dataset I am usign there are more column name endings than jsut two.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `filter` and return a dictionary of dataframes by using a list of values you want to filter by. we need to set the constant columns as the index.

```
filter_vals = ['abc','xyz']


dfs = {
    filter_name: df.set_index(["name", "value"]).filter(like=filter_name)
    for filter_name in filter_vals
}
```

---

```
dfs['xyz']
        x1xyz   x2xyz   x3xyz
name    value
```

---

```
dfs['abc']
        x1abc   x2abc   x3abc
name    value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution just using list comprehension to select the columns:

```
endings = ["xyz", "abc"]
dfs = {e: df[["name", "value"] + [c for c in df.columns if c.endswith(e)]] for e in endings}
```

`dfs` will be a dict where each key is an ending and the value is the DataFrame filtered to contain the relevant columns.